# How do I use a Yongnuo YN200 with a Nikon speedlight?

Tags: nikon, yongnuo, wireless-flash, wireless-triggers, sb-700

I plan to buy a Yongnuo YN200 2.4 GHz 200 Ws TTL flash. But I also have a Nikon D7100 and a Nikon sB700 flash. I want to use and the YN200 and SB700 together.

If I buy a Yongnuo YN560-TX II transmitter, can I use both flashes together?

Answer (score 3):

The YN-560-TX II is a manual-only transmitter that cannot remotely control the YN200 in TTL or HSS. All you can do with a YN-560-TX II is fire it remotely and control its power level and turn its group on/off. To control it in TTL/HSS, you'd need a YN-560-TX Pro transmitter, instead.

Theoretically, you could purchase a YN-622N to attach to the foot of the SB-700 and control it in TTL/HSS from the YN-560-TX Pro, but it would require a firmware update to the YN-622N that was never been issued by Yongnuo and cannot be found.  So, all you can use would be the RF-603 II, or RF-605 transceivers, and that's manual-only.

You would get a *lot* more function and expansion options if you purchased a Godox AD200 instead of the YN200. While an AD200 is more than $100 expensive than a YN200 (at least in 2021), it does several things the YN200 does not. The AD200 has an *interchangeable* head, so you can actually exchange the bare bulb head for a fresnel head, an extension head, or round head, as well as gang two AD200s together in the AD-B2 dual bracket to form the equivalent of a 400 Ws monolight with modeling lights.

And in the Godox system, with any of the three current transmitters (X2T-N, XPro-N, or Flashpoint R2 Pro II-N) you could integrate your SB-700 with full TTL and HSS capability by purchasing and attaching an X1R-N receiver to its foot.

In the Godox system, unlike Yongnuo gear, everything that's 2.4 GHz radio-equipped is in the same system. TTL gear and Manual only gear work well together. And there are a large number of options that are larger than speedlights, including low-cost manual AC-powered strobes, as well as li-ion battery powered TTL/HSS capable ministrobes and monolights, as well as manual pack and head units. Also, unlike Yongnuo, Godox supports TTL/HSS not just for Canon and Nikon, but also for Sony, Fuji, µ4/3, and Pentax, and that support works cross-brand.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the YN200 in TTL or Multi mode it appears you'll need the newer YN560-TX Pro transmitter. If you only want to control manual flash power the older YN560-TX will do.

You'll need Yongnuo YN560/RF605/RF603 receivers to attach to the bottom of the Nikon flash(es) to control and fire them with a YN560-TX. Of course, since the YN560-TX transmitter is manual only, you won't have use of the i-TTL capabilities of the SB unit(s). If you use the YN560-TX Pro transmitter you can use YN622 receivers in YN560RX mode to do TTL with the Nikon flashes.

For just a few buck more you can delve into similar units from Godox. The Godox AD200 has a lot of extra features and more control of manual power levels than the YN200 (both in terms of minimum power setting and tenths of stops vs. one-third stop steps), and the Godox 2.4GHz radio system is totally unified, unlike the patchwork compatibility of the different YN radio protocols. Of course you'd also need Godox receivers to attach to the bottom of your Nikon SB flash(es) to manually control their power settings. Any future expansion into studio type monolights would also be more seamless with Godox, who offers a far larger number of options in that segment than Yongnuo does.

Answer (score 0):

#### The basics

There are two standard general interfaces allowing flashes/speedlights/studio storbes/etc. to work together independent of brand.

The oldest is the flash cable. There are various connectors. The most common are the PC (short for "[Prontor-Compur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prontor-Compur)"), and 3.5mm (or 1/8") audio cable. Cables with one connector at each end are commonly available in the market to interface gear with PC sockets to gear with 3.5mm sockets (this is also the case for a few of the less common flash interface sockets).

The other common interface is optical triggering. Many many (but not all) flashes/speedlights/strobes/etc. can be optically triggered by another flash. One flash serves as the master flash. When it flashes, flashes with optical triggers will fire within the tiniest fraction of a second because triggering happens at the speed of light.

Optical triggering can eliminate some or all of the need for cabling and provides a wireless method of combining multiple flashes that does not depend on proprietary interfaces.

#### The Limitations

Sounds great, but there are limitations.

Generally, neither interface transmits TTL, High Speed Sync, or multi-flash signals between flashes/speedlights/strobes/etc. of different brands. That is because those vary between brands and many ordinary flashes do not provide those advanced features.

On the other hand, TTL, HSS, and multi-flash while nice to have are not necessary for many uses.

If TTL, HSS, and/or multi-flash are important then it is generally best to build a system based on a single manufacturer's standard. For example, to use only Yongnuou or Nikon flashes but not to mix them. Basically, advanced features require picking a proprietary interface.

The success of companies like Godox is that they are producing an entire range of compatible devices - flashes/speedlights/strobes/etc. - that will work together. Compare this to Nikon which only produces speedlights (or more properly on-camera flashes). Nikon does not produce conventional studio strobes and so coordinating Nikon TTL, HSS, and multi-flash with devices like the YN200 requires the use of auxiliary transmitters and triggers.

#### Closing

If you need TTL, HSS, multi-flash, etc., a second Nikon compatible speedlight is the simplest way to add a second light to your existing system...to be pedantic, because the D7100 has a pop-up flash, this would really be a third light. While the YN200 is pretty cool, a second Nikon speedlight will probably be simpler. There are many third party speedlights that are directly compatible with Nikon's system if you are more budget constrained.

Alternatively, it might make sense to build a system around the the YN200 and use the SB700 in a support role when needed. A third option would be to offset the cost of a different brand of lighting by selling the SB700 (that sits better with some people than others).